# sql server adding foreign key the column do not match an existing primary key or unique constraint

Tags: sql-server

Hello I've a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRICING](
    [ID_PRICE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DATA_START] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DATA_END] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PRICING] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_PRICE] ASC,
    [DATA_START] ASC,
    [DATA_END] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

with primary key consisting of 3 columns (I need this triple key)

Now I need to related it to another table like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MOV](
    [ID_MOV] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SALDO] [float] NOT NULL,
    [ID_PRICING_BUY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_PRICING_SELL] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MOV] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_MOV] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I try to add foreign key to the second table adding relation between ID_PRICING_BUY in table MOV and ID_PRICE in table PRICING I get the error
The column do not match an existing primary key or unique constraint

Now what is the correct way to relate these 2 tables?

Thank you.

Comment: I think because in the PRICING table you've PK made from 3 columns. That's why you're getting the error. Add PK similar to the MOV table to the PRICING table and then try to refer it in the MOV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a **compound primary key** made up of 3 columns in your PRICING table, then all foreign keys that reference that **must also include all three columns**.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MOV
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MOV_PRICING
FOREIGN KEY(ID_PRICING_BUY, -new-column-for-start-date-, -new-column-for-end-date-)
REFERENCES dbo.PRICING(ID_PRICE, DATA_START, DATA_END)
```

A foreign key **cannot** reference only part of a primary key.

The only other option would be to create a **unique index** on just `dbo.Pricing(ID_Price)` - then you could reference that unique constraint from a foreign key.

But if you can create a unique index on just `dbo.Pricing(ID_Price)`, the real question becomes why isn't just  `ID_Price` alone the primary key? If it's already unique -> then why add two more columns to your primary key???

Comment: Thank you, the triple key was useful to check data integrity.. But I eliminated. Now ID_Price is unique primary key as you suggested.